# Dagger 2: Update provided object in scope

Tags: android, dagger-2, mosby

Sample scheme:

[image]

It based on [Mosby examples](https://github.com/sockeqwe/mosby/tree/master/sample-mail/src/main/java/com/hannesdorfmann/mosby/sample/mail). I want to share `Project` object between `ProjectFragment` and `ProjectHistoryFragment` with `@PerProject` scope.

ProjectModule:

```
@Module
public class ProjectModule {

    private Project project;

    public ProjectModule(Project project) {
        this.project = project;
    }

    @Provides
    @PerProject
    public Project provideProject() {
        return project;
    }

}
```

`ProjectModule` and `ProjectComponent` will be created by `ProjectFragment` and shared to every `Project-dependent fragment`. Nice.

But there is a problem. What if I need to update the title of `Project`? In my case, `Project` is a final object without any setters. `Project` can be modified only in ProjectFragment, so I can update and reset `module's` value for future injections. But I think that it is bad practice. Can someone give better advice?

Comment: @Alexandra,  Am trying to update my dagger injected object throughout my application reference. Initially it was setted with  no value. Am trying to modify the object from shared preferences. I couln't able to reassign the value in all part of application code. Give me valuable solution to achieve this.Struck on this for two days.

Comment: @SenthilMg create separate well-explained question for this purpose :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Don't** change values within your modules.

A component (and its included modules) have a set of objects they inject where you need them. They get cached, reused, and so on. *Switching* an object will leave you with an *inconsistent state*.
If you need to change an object then **create a new component, with new modules.**

If you still need to change the project *object* without recreating everything, then don't inject the `Project` itself but rather some `ProjectManager`, which could also implement some `Observable` pattern to notify you if the `Project` changed. This way you can modify your project and react to changes.

Comment: Am not able to update injected object through out the app scope. Let me know feasible way to reassign the object using dagger 2.Struck on this issue for 2 days

Comment: Worth a try, it could be done using LiveData as well.